# rescaling and correlations

Tags: r, correlation

Hi if I rescale a series of numeric variables from, say 1 to 6 to 0 to 1, will the Pearson correlation coefficients be different? I think so, but I'd like to ask people here.

```
#Set up some variables that run from 1 to 6
#in my data set these are Likert items
var1<-sample(seq(1,6,1), replace=T, size=100)
var2<-sample(seq(1,6,1), replace=T, size=100)
var3<-sample(seq(1,6,1), replace=T, size=100)
var4<-sample(seq(1,6,1), replace=T, size=100)
var5<-sample(seq(1,6,1), replace=T, size=100)
var6<-sample(seq(1,6,1), replace=T, size=100)
#make a data frame of all
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
#make a data frame of the same data frame, but rescaled from 1 to 6 to 0 to 1
df2<-data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) scales::rescale(x, c(0,1),c(1,6))))
#To my mind, if they are identical, this should produce a matrix of zeros,    but it doesn't, so rescaling changes the correlation coefficients.
cor(df)-cor(df2)
```

Comment: How do you rescale? Are you just subtracting one and divide by five? In that case that is just a linear transformation and the correlation should remain unchanged.

Comment: I'm not sure: The rescale() function is doing the work.

Comment: If it is not documented what that function does then you should stay well away from it.

Comment: @MaartenBuis In OP's code it does (x - 1) / (6 - 1) * (1 - 0) + 0, i.e., exactly what you have assumed.

Comment: @spindoctor Study this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059 You get a matrix of numeric zeros (within floating point number precision) with your code.

Comment: @Roland I have read the R Inferno and never really understood how this would ever matter.  I hope this is not fatal to my analyses.

Comment: Basically, think of floating point numbers as something associated with an uncertainty. This uncertainty is a consequence of the number of bits used to represent these numbers. If you were to increase the number of bits, you could decrease the uncertainty (libraries implementing arbitrary precision numbers do this). The uncertainty of floating point numbers on your system is given in `help(".Machine")`. Usually, any calculated number below about 2.22e-16 cannot be distinguished from zero with normal floating point precision. That's why R often prints small p-values as `< 2.22e-16`.